# Why the query string parameter gets appended after the execution of the JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, php, query-string

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <h2 id="title">Choose a background Theme</h2>
        <div id="black"></div>
        <div id="orange"></div>
        <div id="brown"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to store the color clicked in the div in session parameter now to assign the value I am trying to append it to the query string so I can use `$_GET` variable to store it in the session variable

```
<script>
    var c_selected;
    window.onload = function () {

        document.getElementById("black").addEventListener("click", function () {
            setBackground("black");

        });
        document.getElementById("orange").addEventListener("click", function () {
            setBackground("orange");
        });
        document.getElementById("brown").addEventListener("click", function () {

            setBackground("brown");
        });

    };

    function setBackground(scolor) {
        location.href = (location.href.split("?").length > 1) ? location.href.split("?")[0] + "?color=" + scolor : "?color=" + scolor;
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = scolor
        document.getElementById(scolor).style.border = "thick solid white";
        if (c_selected) {
            document.getElementById(c_selected).style.border = "none";
        }
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = "white";
        <?php $_SESSION['THEME_COLOR'] = isset($_GET['color']) ? $_GET['color'] : "white"; ?>
        c_selected = scolor;
    }


</script>
```

But now as soon as I click any `<div>` the background color gets executed for a split second and any go backs to the default white background and the query string is appended only after the function is executed.

Please explain the reason why this happens and not just the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're changing `location.href`, you're reloading the page, but as the script continues to run, you're able to see when you change color properties.

Take a look, I've only commented the line where you are changing `location.href`.

If you want to use the color as a querystring parameter, you should use hash **#** parameters

```js
  var c_selected;
  window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("black").addEventListener("click", function() {
    setBackground("black");

  });
  document.getElementById("orange").addEventListener("click", function() {
    setBackground("orange");
  });
  document.getElementById("brown").addEventListener("click", function() {

    setBackground("brown");
  });

};

function setBackground(scolor) {
  
  /*location.href = (location.href.split("?").length > 1) ? location.href.split("?")[0] + "?color=" + scolor : "?color=" + scolor;*/
  
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = scolor;
  document.getElementById(scolor).style.border = "thick solid white";
  return;
  if (c_selected) {
    document.getElementById(c_selected).style.border = "none";
  }
  
  
  c_selected = scolor;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

    <h2 id="title">Choose a background Theme</h2>
    <div id="black">Black</div>
    <div id="orange">Orange</div>
    <div id="brown">Brown</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But Than how do I retrieve # querystring parameter in php?

Comment: I think you're mixin concepts, If you want to save the var color in a php, there's no need to reload the full page to accomplish this. The best way is to make an ajax call to an external page that will save it. So the user experience will be much better with no refresh at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the `location.href` by changing the query parameter, you make the browser reload the page, since this represents a new location. To prevent that, you need to change the hash `location.href`, using the `#` instead of `?` as delimiter.

If you want to reload the page, you need to actually set the background color after the page has loaded, right now you are attaching click handlers, which call `setBackground()`, what in turn reloads the page.

```
window.onload = function () { 
 /*add click handlers*/ 
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = "<?php $_SESSION['THEME_COLOR'] = isset($_GET['color']) ? $_GET['color'] : "white"; ?>";
}
```

There is no need to change the background color in `setBackground()`, because that function makes the browser reload the page, so you wont see the result very long.